# Android databinding: BindingAdapter vs InverseBindingAdapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

What is the difference between the two?

When should use one or the other?

When I define a `BindingAdapter` do I have to create an inverse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting myself, from [*The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development*](https://commonsware.com/Android):

> Two-way binding works well in cases where the
>   way you store the data in the models lines up well with the getters
>   and setters of the associated widget. A `boolean` field in the model
>   works well with the checked property
>   of a `CompoundButton` like a `Switch`, as `CompoundButton` has 
>   an `isChecked()` method returning a `boolean` and a `setChecked()`
>   accepting a `boolean`.
>
> A `BindingAdapter` allows you to create other mappings between data
>   types and properties, but only for the classic model->view binding.
>   To accomplish the same thing in the reverse direction, you wind up
>   creating an `InverseBindingAdapter`. As the name suggests, this serves
>   the same basic role as a `BindingAdapter`, but in the inverse direction,
>   taking data from the widget and preparing it for the model using custom
>   code. Here, the "preparing it for the model" means converting it into
>   a suitable data type for a setter, `Observable` field, etc. for your
>   model.
>
> This is fairly unusual.
>
> The example used in some places is "what if I
>   want to tie a `float` to an `EditText`?". The `InverseBindingAdapter`
>   would look something like this:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static float getFloat(EditText et) {
  try {
    return(Float.parseFloat(et.getText().toString()));
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return(0.0f); // because, um, what else can we do?
  }
}
```

> The problem is if the user types in something that is not a valid
>   floating-point number, like `snicklefritz`. `parseFloat()` will fail
>   with a `NumberFormatException`. You *should* let the user know that their
>   data entry was invalid. However, two-way data binding does not support
>   this, with a default value (e.g., `0.0f`) being handed to the model
>   instead.

So, to answer your questions:

> What is the difference between the two?

`BindingAdapter` helps populate properties where the data types and `View` setters are not something that data binding knows how to handle on its own.

`InverseBindingAdapter` helps populate view-models in two-way binding, where the data types and the `View` getters are not something that data binding knows how to handle on its own.

> When should use one or the other? When I define a BindingAdapter do I have to create an inverse?

Use a `BindingAdapter` when your desired data type (e.g., a `float`) is not something that data binding necessarily knows how to fill into a widget property (e.g., `android:text` on an `EditText`), but you want to bind it anyway.

If you do that, *and* you want to do two-way binding, where user changes in the UI automatically update your view-model, most likely you will need a matching `InverseBindingAdapter` to convert from the property (e.g., text of an `EditText`) to the desired data type (e.g., a `float`).